# Idiomatic and lazy eventually truthy in a list in Clojure

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

I'd like to have a function/macro for checking a list to have truthy value eventually, and I hope the evaluation would be lazy. Here is my illustrative implementation without lazy evaluation:

```
(defn eventual [cols]
  (or (first cols) (if-let [rs (rest cols)]
                     (eventual rs))
                     false))
```

Here is a trivial example to illustrate:

```
(if (eventual [false (+ 1 2) (* 10000 10000)])
  true
  false)
```

I feel that there must be an implication with lazy evaluation. Maybe I'm just blinded at the moment. Please help to help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if a sequence contains at least one truthy element with [`some`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some) function:

```
(some identity col)
```

If you pass it a lazy sequence as `col` it will evaluate its contents up to the first truthy element and won't realise the rest:

```
(let [col (take
            10
            (iterate
              #(do (println "Generating new value from " %) (inc %))
              0))]
  (some #(> % 5) col))
```

produces:

```
Generating new value from  0
Generating new value from  1
Generating new value from  2
Generating new value from  3
Generating new value from  4
Generating new value from  5
true
```

As you can see, values 6..9 are not produces at all.

You also should double check that the `col` you pass to `some` is really lazy and not already realised, because it might confuse you.

Comment: Thanks for helping to getting the real idiomatic one!

Answer (score 2):

Your `eventual` function is as lazy as it can be. It searches eagerly for the first truthy item then stops. But it has problems:

- It fails to terminate on an empty collection. `(rest ())` is `()`,
  which is truthy. Use `next` instead of `rest`. `(next ())` is `nil`,
  which is falsy.
- It is truly recursive. It will blow the stack on a long enough
  search. Try `(eventual (repeat false))`. Since the recursion is
  tail-recursion, you can fix this by using `recur` in its place.
- While we are at it, it is idiomatic to return `nil`, not `false`,
  upon running out of a collection. So drop the final `false`.

We end up with

```
(defn eventual [cols]
  (or (first cols) (if-let [rs (next cols)]
                     (recur rs))))
```

I'm a little queasy about what happens if `cols` is empty. Code based upon [the source for `some`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/010864f8ed828f8d261807b7345f1a539c5b20df/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2583) is clearer:

```
(defn eventual [coll]
    (when (seq coll)
      (or (first coll) (recur next coll))))
```

But using `(some identity col)`, as [Piotrek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37341977/1562315) suggests, is probably best.

Comment: Thanks for finding problems of my implementation, and fixing it.